# Issue with trying to reference a field in a JSON element from a related selection in a SwiftUI Picker

Tags: json, swiftui, reference, picker

In response to @Vadian's request I have provided the code for a redacted View to add a Client with the relevant code for context as well as a sample JSON element.  I have attempted various ways to create a reference back to the 'flag' in the JSON element related to the 'selectedCountry' over the last two days with no progress, as I understand that JSON does not have reference capability.  The code inside the Picker works perfectly and displays a list of 'country.name's & 'country.flagImage's.  I am trying to display the flag again after exiting the Picker.  The secondary issue that 'selectedCountry' default setting of "Canada" does not appear initially in the Picker despite being an @State var.  Any help would be appreciated!!!

CountryModel:

```
import SwiftUI

class Country: Codable, Identifiable, Comparable, ObservableObject {
    
        static func == (lhs: Country, rhs: Country) -> Bool {
            lhs.name == rhs.name
        }
        
        static func < (lhs: Country, rhs: Country) -> Bool {
            lhs.name < rhs.name
        }
    let name: String
    let isoAlpha3: String
    let flag: Data?
    var flagImage : UIImage? {
        guard let flagData = flag else { return nil }
        return UIImage(data: flagData)
    }
    
    struct HeadingData: Codable,Identifiable, Hashable {
        let id: Int
        let name: String
        let isoAlpha3: String
        let flag: Data
    }
    
    struct CurrencyData: Codable, Equatable, Identifiable, Hashable {
        let id: UUID
        let code: String
        let name: String
        let symbol: String
    }
}
```

View (simplified):

```
import SwiftUI

struct SampleAddClient: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var dbContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    let countries: [Country] = Bundle.main.decode("Countries.json")
    @State private var inputName: String = ""
    @State private var inputAddress: String = ""
    @State private var selectedCountry: String = "Canada"
    let client: ClientEntity?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 12) {
            HStack {
                Text("Name:")
                TextField("Client Name", text: $inputName)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            }//: HSTACK1
            HStack {
                Text("Address")
                TextField("Client Address", text: $inputAddress)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            }//: HSTACK2
            HStack {
                Text("Client's Host Country:")
                Spacer()
                
                VStack {
                    Picker(selection: $selectedCountry,
                           label: Text("Host Country:")) {
                        ForEach(countries) { country in
                            HStack {
                                Text(country.name).tag(country.name)
                                // Find Flag
                                if let flagImage = country.flagImage {
                                    Image(uiImage: flagImage).tag(country.flag)
                                } else {
                                    let _ = print("Fail")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                           .padding(.horizontal, 0)
                           .padding()
                           .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
                }//: INNER PICKER VSTACK
            }//: HSTACK3
            //Image(THIS IS WHERE THE FLAG IMAGE SHOULD GO.)
        }//: OUTER VSTACK
        .disableAutocorrection(true)
        .padding()
        .navigationBarTitle("Add Client")
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button("Save") {
                    let newName = inputName.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
                    let newAddress = inputAddress.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
                    let newCountry = selectedCountry
                    
                    if !newName.isEmpty {
                        Task(priority: .high) {
                            await storeClient(clientName: newName, clientAddress: newAddress, clientHostCountry: newCountry)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }//: TOOLBAR
    }
    
    func storeClient(clientName: String, clientAddress: String, clientHostCountry: String) async {
        await dbContext.perform {
            
            let newClient = ClientEntity(context: dbContext)
            newClient.clientName = clientName
            newClient.clientAddress = clientAddress
            newClient.clientHostCountry = clientHostCountry
        }
        do {
            try dbContext.save()
            dismiss()
        } catch {
            print("Error saving record! \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}

struct SampleAddClient_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SampleAddClient(client: nil)
    }
}
```

JSON Sample:

> {
> "id": 39,
> "name": "Canada",
> "isoAlpha2": "CA",
> "isoAlpha3": "CAN",
> "isoNumeric": 124,
> "currency": {
> "code": "CAD",
> "name": "Dollar",
> "symbol": "$"
> },
> "flag": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB4AAAAUCAYAAACaq43EAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAyRpVFh0WE1MOmNvbS5hZG9iZS54bXAAAAAAADw/eHBhY2tldCBiZWdpbj0i77u/IiBpZD0iVzVNME1wQ2VoaUh6cmVTek5UY3prYzlkIj8+IDx4OnhtcG1ldGEgeG1sbnM6eD0iYWRvYmU6bnM6bWV0YS8iIHg6eG1wdGs9IkFkb2JlIFhNUCBDb3JlIDUuMy1jMDExIDY2LjE0NTY2MSwgMjAxMi8wMi8wNi0xNDo1NjoyNyAgICAgICAgIj4gPHJkZjpSREYgeG1sbnM6cmRmPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5LzAyLzIyLXJkZi1zeW50YXgtbnMjIj4gPHJkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbiByZGY6YWJvdXQ9IiIgeG1sbnM6eG1wPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvIiB4bWxuczp4bXBNTT0iaHR0cDovL25zLmFkb2JlLmNvbS94YXAvMS4wL21tLyIgeG1sbnM6c3RSZWY9Imh0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5jb20veGFwLzEuMC9zVHlwZS9SZXNvdXJjZVJlZiMiIHhtcDpDcmVhdG9yVG9vbD0iQWRvYmUgUGhvdG9zaG9wIENTNiAoTWFjaW50b3NoKSIgeG1wTU06SW5zdGFuY2VJRD0ieG1wLmlpZDpFREI0MDA4MjE3NzMxMUUyODY3Q0FBOTFCQzlGNjlDRiIgeG1wTU06RG9jdW1lbnRJRD0ieG1wLmRpZDpFREI0MDA4MzE3NzMxMUUyODY3Q0FBOTFCQzlGNjlDRiI+IDx4bXBNTTpEZXJpdmVkRnJvbSBzdFJlZjppbnN0YW5jZUlEPSJ4bXAuaWlkOkVEQjQwMDgwMTc3MzExRTI4NjdDQUE5MUJDOUY2OUNGIiBzdFJlZjpkb2N1bWVudElEPSJ4bXAuZGlkOkVEQjQwMDgxMTc3MzExRTI4NjdDQUE5MUJDOUY2OUNGIi8+IDwvcmRmOkRlc2NyaXB0aW9uPiA8L3JkZjpSREY+IDwveDp4bXBtZXRhPiA8P3hwYWNrZXQgZW5kPSJyIj8+IgrEzAAAAaZJREFUeNrEVktqwlAUPVr/TRXqB0QMHXbSqXsQdCRuQbsBR3bmJBtw7A4cuwyLBQNCKdgOVBCpIv7aUx8PiVZtNCo9cHm5yb3v3E/eTWwEPrEOlwtot4FIBGfBbAbE40C3u3HbsZQb/APslj3LZUDTrDMvS80NcbnIToc7MZkY18JO2K8wHu/2mU7JSIS/eRxHRTmfA6USMBjI3gnkckAoBBQKgNd7oYwFEomt6Hl3t99+T8Z20zdyhWZTrvn8tt3jo1wbjd2+R2fc65HpNFksksEgqWlkv0/a7Zs+7TZZqZCKQj49kckk+fr6Z8bmpY5GN5+nUqTTaeg2mwxuPRi327TUfxMLp3x+u6dmks1KX8vErRbp8x1PLKReP4H4+5us1cjb28MJPR6yWiW/vk7sscD7O3l/b06qqqSuH3ScDj/Hi4XceB+pqMpodIHJdXUFPDwAfj+gqsYWTifw9gaEw8D19QUm12xGDgaG/vJCPj8b+nAobc4yudYhMgsEDF3XpaygKNLmQDgsf9Y+PszH4kWIYzFgsTiJeGjJM5M56Q/kR4ABAHxxYPgLzAdZAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"
> },
>
> {
> "id": 224,
> "name": "Ukraine",
> "isoAlpha2": "UA",
> "isoAlpha3": "UKR",
> "isoNumeric": 804,
> "currency": {
> "code": "UAH",
> "name": "Hryvnia",
> "symbol": "₴"
> },
> "flag": "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"
> },

[Add Client with blue rectangle showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sIla.png)

Entire View code as it stands at the moment.  Still some work to do on the many-to-many Contact capture:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct AddClientView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var dbContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ContactEntity.contactLastName, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default) private var listofContacts: FetchedResults<ContactEntity>
    @StateObject var viewModel = CountryModel()
    @AppStorage("country") var defaultCountry: String?
    @State private var inputName: String = ""
    @State private var inputAddress: String = ""
    @State private var inputIndustry: String = ""
    @State private var inputPhone: String = ""
    @State private var inputComments: String = ""
    @State private var inputCreated: Date = Date()
    @State private var inputUpdated: Date = Date()
    @State private var inputExisting: Bool = false
    @State private var selectedCountry: Country?
    //@State private var inputWebSite: URL
    @State private var selectedContact: [ContactEntity] = []
    //@State private var country = []
    let flag = "flag"
    //@State private var flagImage: Data
    //let updatedContact: ContactEntity?
    let client: ClientEntity?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 12) {
            HStack {
                Text("Name:")
                TextField("Client Name", text: $inputName)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            }//: HSTACK1
            HStack {
                Text("Address")
                TextField("Client Address", text: $inputAddress)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            }//: HSTACK2
            HStack {
                Text("Client's Host Country")
                Spacer()
                
                VStack {
                    Picker(selection: $selectedCountry,
                           label: Text("Host Country:")) {
                        ForEach(viewModel.countries) { country in
                            HStack {
                            Text(country.name)
                                if let flagImage = country.flagImage {
                                    Image(uiImage: flagImage).tag(country.flag)
                            } else {
                                Image(systemName: "questionmark")
                            }
                            }.tag(country as Country?)//: HSTACK6
                        }
                    }
//                           .onAppear {
//                               invokeDefaultCountry()
//                           }
                           .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                           .padding()
                           .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
                }//: INNER PICKER VSTACK
            }//: HSTACK3
            VStack {
                Text("Selected Country: \(selectedCountry?.name ?? "No Name")")
                if let flagImage = selectedCountry?.flagImage {
                    Image(uiImage: flagImage)
                }
            }
            Button(action: {  // Remove before production
                printvalue() // To test for change of country
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise")
                    .font(.title)
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Industry")
                TextField("Client Industry", text: $inputIndustry)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            }//: HSTACK4
            HStack {
                Text("Phone Number")
                TextField("Client Phone", text: $inputPhone)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            }//: HSTACK5
            Toggle("Existing Client?", isOn: $inputExisting)
                .toggleStyle(.switch)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
            HStack {
                //                Text("Contact")
                //                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                //                    Text(selectedContact?.contactFirstName ?? "No Contacts yet")
                //                        .foregroundColor(selectedContact != nil ? Color.black : Color.gray)
                //                    NavigationLink(destination: AddContactView(), label: {
                //                        Text("Select Contact")
                //                    })
                //                }
                VStack {
                    Picker(selection: $selectedContact,
                           label: Text("Contact:")) {
                        ForEach(listofContacts) { contact in
                            Text("\(contact.contactFirstName ?? "") \(contact.contactLastName ?? "")").tag(contact.contactLastName)
                        }
                    }
                           .padding(.horizontal, 0)
                           .padding()
                           .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
                }//: INNER PICKER VSTACK
                Print("1. \(Set(selectedContact))")
            }//: HSTACK6
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            Spacer()
        }//:Outer VSTACK
        .disableAutocorrection(true)
        .padding()
        .navigationBarTitle("Add Client")
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button("Save") {
                    let newName = inputName.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
                    let newAddress = inputAddress.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
                    let newCountry = selectedCountry?.name
                    let newIndustry = inputIndustry
                    let newPhone = inputPhone
                    let newComment = inputComments
                    let newCreatedDate = inputCreated
                    let newUpdatedDate = inputUpdated
                    let newExisting = inputExisting
                    if !newName.isEmpty {
                        Task(priority: .high) {
                            await storeClient(clientName: newName, clientAddress: newAddress, clientHostCountry: newCountry ?? "No Name", clientIndustry: newIndustry, clientPhoneNumber: newPhone, clientComments: newComment, clientCreated: newCreatedDate, clientUpdated: newUpdatedDate, clientExisting: newExisting)
                            Print("3. \(Set(selectedContact))")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }//: TOOLBAR
    }
    
    
    // TODO: - Code required to 1. Update @AppStorage with default country & 2. to invoke this.
//    func invokeDefaultCountry() {
//        selectedCountry?.name = defaultCountry ?? "Country?"
//    }
    
    func storeClient(clientName: String, clientAddress: String, clientHostCountry: String, clientIndustry: String, clientPhoneNumber: String, clientComments: String, clientCreated: Date, clientUpdated: Date, clientExisting: Bool) async {
        await dbContext.perform {
            
            let newClient = ClientEntity(context: dbContext)
            //let existingContact = ContactEntity(context:dbContext)
            //            var contactArray: [ContactEntity] {
            //                let contact = newClient.contact as! Set<ContactEntity>
            //                return contact.sorted {
            //                    $0.wrappedValue < $1.wrappedValue
            //                }
            //            }
            newClient.clientName = clientName
            newClient.clientAddress = clientAddress
            newClient.clientHostCountry = clientHostCountry
            newClient.clientIndustry = clientIndustry
            newClient.clientPhoneNumber = clientPhoneNumber
            newClient.clientComments = clientComments
            newClient.clientCreated = clientCreated
            newClient.clientUpdated = clientUpdated
            newClient.clientExisting = clientExisting
            let uniqueContact = Set(selectedContact)
            Print("Unique \(uniqueContact)")
            Print("4. \(Set(selectedContact))")
            for contact in uniqueContact {
                Print("Contact \(contact)")
            newClient.addToContacts(contact)
                fetchContact()
                //existingContact.contactChampion = ((updatedContact?.contactChampion ?? false))
                //existingContact.addToClients(newClient)
            }
            //newClient.cover = UIImage(named: "bookcover")?.pngData()
            //newCient.thumbnail = UIImage(named: "bookthumbnail")?.pngData()
            do {
                try dbContext.save()
                dismiss()
            } catch {
                print("Error saving record! \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func printvalue() {  // Remove before production
        print("End of Picker: \($selectedCountry)")
        print("Selected Country: \(String(describing: selectedCountry))")
        print("Default Country: \(defaultCountry ?? "Nothing in App Storage")")
    }
    func printAnything() { // Remove before production
        print("From change - did it?")
        print("Selected Country: \(String(describing: selectedCountry))")
    }
    
    func fetchContact() {
        print(client?.contactsArray ?? "Empty")
        @FetchRequest (
            sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ContactEntity.contactLastName, ascending: true)], predicate: NSPredicate( format: "contactLastName == \(selectedContact)")) var updatedContact: FetchedResults<ContactEntity>
        print(selectedContact)
    }
}

struct AddClientView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    let client: ClientEntity?
    static var previews: some View {
        AddClientView(client: nil).environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try a small re-structure of your code using an `ObservableObject` model to hold your `countries: [Country]`. And a `selectedCountry: Country?` for the `Picker` selection,
such as in this example code (works well for me):

```
// -- here
struct Country: Codable, Identifiable, Comparable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID() // <-- here
    
    let name: String
    let isoAlpha3: String
    let flag: Data?
    var flagImage: UIImage? {
        guard let flagData = flag else { return nil }
        return UIImage(data: flagData)
    }
    static func == (lhs: Country, rhs: Country) -> Bool {
        lhs.name == rhs.name
    }
    static func < (lhs: Country, rhs: Country) -> Bool {
        lhs.name < rhs.name
    }
}

struct HeadingData: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let isoAlpha3: String
    let flag: Data
}

struct CurrencyData: Codable, Equatable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: UUID
    let code: String
    let name: String
    let symbol: String
}

// -- here
class CountryModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var countries: [Country] = []
    
    init() {
        self.countries = Bundle.main.decode("Countries.json")
    }
}

struct SampleAddClient: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var dbContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = CountryModel()  // <-- here

    @State private var inputName: String = ""
    @State private var inputAddress: String = ""
    @State private var selectedCountry: Country?   // <-- here
    let client: ClientEntity?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 12) {
            HStack {
                Text("Name:")
                TextField("Client Name", text: $inputName)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            }//: HSTACK1
            HStack {
                Text("Address")
                TextField("Client Address", text: $inputAddress)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            }//: HSTACK2
            HStack {
                Text("Client's Host Country:")
                Spacer()
                
                VStack {
                    Picker(selection: $selectedCountry, label: Text("Host Country:")) {
                        ForEach(viewModel.countries) { country in
                            HStack {
                                Text(country.name)
                                if let flagImage = country.flagImage {
                                    Image(uiImage: flagImage)
                                } else {
                                    Image(systemName: "questionmark")
                                }
                            }.tag(country as Country?) // <-- here
                        }
                    }
                        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                        .padding()
                        .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
                }
            }//: HSTACK3
            // THIS IS WHERE THE FLAG IMAGE SHOULD GO.
            // -- here
            VStack {
                Text("selectedCountry: \(selectedCountry?.name ?? "no name")")
                if let flagImage = selectedCountry?.flagImage {
                    Image(uiImage: flagImage)
                }
            }
        }//: OUTER VSTACK
        .onAppear {
            selectedCountry = viewModel.countries.first // <-- here if required
        }
        .disableAutocorrection(true)
        .padding()
        .navigationBarTitle("Add Client")
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button("Save") {
                    let newName = inputName.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
                    let newAddress = inputAddress.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
                    let newCountry = selectedCountry
                    
                    if !newName.isEmpty {
                        Task(priority: .high) {
                            await storeClient(clientName: newName, clientAddress: newAddress, clientHostCountry: newCountry)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }//: TOOLBAR
    }
    
    func storeClient(clientName: String, clientAddress: String, clientHostCountry: String) async {
        await dbContext.perform {

            let newClient = ClientEntity(context: dbContext)
            newClient.clientName = clientName
            newClient.clientAddress = clientAddress
            newClient.clientHostCountry = clientHostCountry
        }
        do {
            try dbContext.save()
            dismiss()
        } catch {
            print("Error saving record! \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT-1: using `Group` to cater for view limit:

You can use this approach:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var view1: some View  {
        Group {
            Text("view1 a")
            Text("view1 b")
            // ...
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            view1
            // ...view2 ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works and I am grateful.  It is clever to equate the 'selectedCountry' to the entire JSON element.  I don't fully understand some of the Swift code and will get back with some questions tomorrow.  In the meantime, shouldn't Country struct have let id: UUID instead of let id = UUID()? The compiler gives a warning error.  Secondly, how do I get rid of the ugly blue rectangle before the Picker selection "Afghanistan".  Sorry - can't print a screenshot in a Comment.

Comment: Glad it's working for you. When you use `let id = UUID()` it means the `id` is set for good.
 The compiler gives you a very friendly message to say that it will not be decoded,
  and that is what you want, since the `Country` json data does not have a `id` to decode.
 Some people get scared by the compiler advice, so to remove it you can add
 `enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {  case name,isoAlpha3,flag }` to `Country`.
 Note, `id` is missing.
Sorry but I don't see any blue rectangle before the Picker, you must be using
 some code that you are not showing in your question.

Comment: The enum with the coding key works.  Thank you.  The blue rectangle persists - I have double checked your code against mine.  Maybe it contains other data from the JSON element?  In fact this raises the question - how does the compiler know to display the country's name?  Would you know offhand why the Picker list displays in reverse order?

Comment: I have moved the code to the real project - still working, but still blue triangle.  So, I called a function: print("Selected Country: \(String(describing: selectedCountry))").  The console displays: Selected Country: Optional(B2Bv1_3.Country(id: 6CB6753D-070D-4074-B01D-A0EAC1FB5FF1, name: "Ukraine", isoAlpha3: "UKR", flag: Optional(953 bytes))).  Is this not the contents of the rectangle, perhaps?

Comment: To make the picker display the countries in alphabetical order (for example), use 
 `.onAppear { viewModel.countries.sort(by: {$0.name < $1.name}) ... }`.
 To track down your blue rectangle issue, could you edit your post 
 and add the json data for `Ukraine`, after the data you already have for `Canada`.

Comment: Ukraine JSON element added.  I will also try to add a screenshot & the relevant code as it is now.

Comment: tried the new data, and all works well for me.
Since there are too many missing parts (especially the CoreData), I can only try my test code. Tested code on real devices, **not** Preview. 
In `AddClientView` right after your `//: OUTER VSTACK`,  you should have `.onAppear { viewModel.countries.sort(by: {$0.name < $1.name});  selectedCountry = viewModel.countries.first  }`. 

Do not add `.tag(country.flag)` to `Image(uiImage: flagImage)`, remove it.
Note also, that there is a limit of 10 views that you can have in a View. 
You can bypass this limit by using `Group{...}` (look it up).

Comment: Good advice about the Views - the code needs a lot of tidying up.  I tried it on a real device and still get the blue rectangle.  Very strange.

Comment: yeah, strange. Gather a minimal reproducible example, and ask a new question about the blue rectangle. Note, your json data should really be `[ {..}, {..}]`

Comment: Your support is much appreciated.  A set of square brackets is present on each side of the 239 country elements.

Comment: Quick question regarding the limit on number of Views in a View - If I move some of the views to an extension containing a computed property, does this reduce the view count?  I want to do this anyway for reusability.

Comment: I've just realised that an extension is associated with a specific view - so no good for reusability, unless it is 'extension View { .. }', but this will probably affect performance if it is associated with 50-60 views, but only required for about 10.

Comment: By the way, the blue rectangle only appears once a country has been selected.

Comment: Updated my answer with the approach I often use for grouping views.

Answer (score 0):

Put tag on entire picker's row

```
    HStack {
        Text(country.name)
        // Find Flag
        if let flagImage = country.flagImage {
            Image(uiImage: flagImage).tag(country.flag)
        } else {
            let _ = print("Fail")
        }
    }.tag(country.name)     // << here !!
```